# Should Cloud Endpoints Frameworks library be included when deploying?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-python27

[Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python) has a step to include the endpoint library under lib directory.

When deploying apparently the packages that are getting installed in this directory are conflicting with AppEngine environment.

After "Generating the OpenAPI configuration file", and before deploying I deleted the 'lib' directory.

I haven't noticed any issues so far.

Is there any potential problem with not pushing the packages under 'lib' directory along with your App code?

Answer (score 1):

The files in the *lib* directory allow you to extend GAE beyond its [built in third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27). Per the [documentation on the subject](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library), you do need to upload any third-party libraries that you wish to use.

Cloud Endpoints Frameworks v2 recently came out of beta, so it is entirely possible that it is now included in the built in libraries, but that's not something should be counted on as the package *endpoints 2.0* is not currently listed as being available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27).

So, to answer your question, yes, there are certainly serious problems that you could run into by not including the *lib* folder. For libraries that are not known to be built in, it seems to me that it would be wise to control the versions you need via the *lib* folder.

Further info, per @Dan Cornilescu's comment:

If you need to use a built in library, you should list it in the `libraries:` section of your `app.yaml`, as detailed in the [app.yaml documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#libraries).

Comment: Wouldn't a built-in library have to also be explicitly listed in the `libraries` section of the service's `.yaml` file to be accessible in the service's code?

Comment: Yes! Good catch. I should have mentioned that as well. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @HondaGuy and Dan.

I already had 'endpoints' added to 'libraries' and so far that seems to be working when I deployed without 'that lib' folder.